# Ansible - is there a equivalent of ansible_group_priority for hosts when using dynamic inventory scripts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

In reference to my Title: [Ansible group vars priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120793/ansible-group-vars-priority)

I am attempting to stage variable changes in a dynamic inventory source but the local host_var file (./host_vars/hostname) takes precedence.  When I like my staged change, then I would remove it and store it, longterm, in a git repo.

Thanks in advance,